# Requesting a DNS glue record from the .edu TLD

Tags: domain-name-system, nameserver

I am a System Administrator at a small college. We have a .edu domain. We are thinking of adding a Route53 server (Amazon AWS) to the mix for redundancy.

Wanted to know, how would we add a glue record for the additional NS in the .edu TLD? Is it possible? I am admittedly far from an expert in these advanced DNS topics. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I presume that you want to add another permanent NS IP for your .edu domain?  If this is the case, you'll have to contact the .edu domain administrator which is apparently located at http://net.educause.edu/edudomain and work through them.